# Javamail automatically detect settings based on EHLO response

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

There is huge list of java mail properties

https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html
https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html

Based on mail server configuration we have set appropriate settings.

But can't javamail decide which properties to be set in some cases, so that client code don't have to worry about setting certain properties.

For example, if we telnet SMTP server and use EHLO command, it gives following type of response based on response of EHLO command

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP jw13sm5401749pad.48 - gsmtp
ehlo
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [114.143.231.33]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
250 AUTH=LOGIN
```

I understand not all configurations are returned through EHLO command but whatever is returned based on that can't javamail set some properties ( like starttls, auth enalble etc)
( Not sure if something exist for IMAP/POP3 as well ).

Comment: Which properties? For example, that output shows that STARTTLS is *available* at that server. It's up to the client whether it *wants* to talk TLS for example, and to provide the appropriate SSL truststores and so forth if so. That's not something that could be automated.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm talking about javamail properties that clients has to set. If javamail could figure out certain thing on its own then clients don't have worry about setting certain properties.I didn't find any way but wanted to check if there any.

Comment: JavaMail does adapt its behavior based on the capabilities of the server, but most of the properties you can set reflect user preferences.  For example, if your preference is to use STARTTLS whenever it's available, set the mail.smtp.starttls.enable property to true.  However, if your preference is to fail if STARTTLS isn't available, set mail.smtp.starttls.required to true.  JavaMail can't know your preference.  Some properties could probably have better defaults, but they haven't been changed to maintain compatibility with previous releases.